# How to show animated gif using Bootstrap button when clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

i know how to show loading... text when user click on Bootstrap button. this way i do it

http://jsfiddle.net/YCst4/1/

```
add two dependency files
1) bootstrap.min.css 
2) bootstrap.min.js 

<button class="btn" id="button" data-text-loading="Loading...">Press Me</button>
$('#button').button();

$('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).button('loading');
});
```

now how could i show this animated gif http://www.bba-reman.com/images/fbloader.gif at the place of button when user will click on button.

please guide me how to do with sample code if possible. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this:

```
$('#button').button();

$('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).html('<img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/images/fbloader.gif" />');
});
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YCst4/857/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, have a look at this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YCst4/855/)**.

I used CSS `background` attribute and jQuery `.show()` and .`hide()` methods:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".loader").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<img src="[loader-url]" />');
});
```